# Regular Expression (.*)@(.*)

Tags: regex

What does this regular expression stand for (.*)@(.*). I came to know that (.*) matches any character with period any number of times.

But I couldn't understand the meaning properly. Also, what does two of them separated by @ mean?

Comment: The title suggests (.*) and the question says (.). Possible typo?

Comment: I think it's just an emoticon

Comment: it matches a string that has a literal `@` somewhere in it (like an email address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(.*)@(.*)` can match any of the following:

`@`, `.@.`, `..@.`, `jbkbhjh...@...njbh` ...

`*` means one or many characters.

so this regex means **a `@` symbol enclosed by any number of chars**

> Also, what does two of them separated by @ mean

Answer to this is: the `@` symbol is **required** for a text to match this regex

Comment: You mean to say that if I have testing123@gmail.com, then this command would give me "testing123" and "gmail.com" separately ?

Comment: no, the entire string `testing123@gmail.com` matches this regex, so if you test this string this regex, it will return true

Comment: So, it gives me output as testing123 and gmail.com separately, right?

Comment: yes. it will return the email

Answer (score 1):

`.*@.*` matches any string containing the `@` character
Example of strings that this pattern would match

- `@`
- `@qe`
- `asrrd@`
- `qw3e@as112d`

`(.*)@(.*)`  would just return whatever is before and after the `@` character

Example:

- for `@` would return two empty strings `''` , `''`
- for `@qe` rule will return `''` and `'qe'`
- for `asrrd@` would return `'asrrd'` and `''`
- for `qw3e@as112d` would return `'qw3e'` and `'as112d'`